# Use Mathematica to solve equation derive the probability distributions using the Principle of Maximum Entropy

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

I am reading the article [Deriving probability distributions using the Principle of Maximum Entropy](https://sgfin.github.io/2017/03/16/Deriving-probability-distributions-using-the-Principle-of-Maximum-Entropy/) and trying to derive some of the equations in it automatically using Mathematica.

I want to solve the system of equations below automatically.

> $$ 1+\text{ln} p(x)-\lambda_0=0 $$
> $$ \int_a^b p(x) dx=1 $$

My code is

```
Solve[1 - λ0 + Log[p[x]] == 0  &&  
  Integrate[p[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 1 , {p[x], λ0} ]
```

But I get the error output,

```
Solve: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
```

What should I do to make Mathematica able to solve the above system of equations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: the mathematical description in the OP has a difference compared to the code provided, namely the limits of integration. I am following the TeX version of the equations provided.

Solve the first one

```
sltn1 = Assuming[Element[λ0, Reals], 
   Solve[1 - λ0 + Log[p[x]] == 0, p[x]]] // First
```

and use the solution to solve the other one

```
Solve[Integrate[p[x] /. sltn1, {x, a, b}] == 1, λ0] // First
```

Edit: ask yourself this. Since, we don't know what

$$
\begin{equation}
\int^b_a dx ~ p(x)
\end{equation}
$$

is unless we specify $p(x)$, why should Mathematica evaluate it? This logic would lead you to break the problem into smaller parts that you can and the software can solve.

Edit: after the discussion in the comments with the author of the OP, many thanks for the input and verification, people who are using versions earlier than `13` should use

```
Assuming[{Element[λ0, Reals]},   Simplify[Solve[1 - λ0 + Log[p[x]] == 0, p[x]]]]
```

and the rest of the answer as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy answer. But I am still get the `Solve: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.` error.  https://ibb.co/xmCGPCc

Comment: @Domen I am using 12.1.1.0

Comment: @benjaminchanming try with a fresh kernel. Do `Quit[]` and then run the commands in the order I wrote them down and let me know. I hardly think that `12.1.1` will have troubles, so probably so previous definitions are messing up.

Comment: @benjaminchanming your notebook should look like [**`this`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jLCm.png). Since your screenshot starts at input 11 I cannot know what happens in 11 lines of code I don't see :-) that's the reason for suggesting a clean kernel

Comment: Thanks. It's strange that the `Assuming[Element[\[Lambda]0, Reals]`  seems not work on my Mathematica. https://ibb.co/7Cr2ytw

Comment: @benjaminchanming can you try a different syntax? `Solve[1 - \[Lambda]0 + Log[p[x]] == 0, p[x], Assumptions -> {Element[\[Lambda]0, Reals]}]`

Comment: @benjaminchanming and also,  please try this one `Assuming[{Element[\[Lambda]0, Reals]}, 
  Solve[1 - \[Lambda]0 + Log[p[x]] == 0, p[x]]] // First` and let me know if any of them works

Comment: sorry, none of them works on my computer :(  https://ibb.co/tP6NN9X

Comment: @benjaminchanming perhaps in earlier versions you should wrap it inside a `Simplify` let's say. For example, does this `Assuming[{Element[\[Lambda]0, Reals]}, 
 Simplify[Solve[1 - \[Lambda]0 + Log[p[x]] == 0, p[x]]]]` work?

Comment: @benjaminchanming please try this last one, which should work I believe and let me know so I can update the answer appropriately

Comment: Oh, the last one works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @benjaminchanming thanks for letting me know. I will update this detail in my answer :-)